# Does this cause memory leakage by not freeing the function pointer? C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

Does this code architecture cause memory leakage by not freeing `m_func`?

And could this be tempered with if this code would be executed at a closed server? Like finding the address of the pointer and replacing the code of the function pointee with malicious code? If so how could I solve this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template <typename Func>
struct endpoint_t {
    void* m_func;
    endpoint_t(Func&& func) : m_func((void*) func) {}
    auto execute() {
        return ((Func*) m_func)();
    }
};
int hello_world() {
    std::cout << "Hello World! \n";
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    endpoint_t end(hello_world);
    end.execute();
}
```

Edit:
This is the actual goal of the code: To store multiple endpoint functions inside a vector.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
template <typename Func>
struct endpoint_t {
    void* m_func;
    endpoint_t(Func&& func) : m_func((void*) func) {}
    auto execute() {
        return ((Func*) m_func)();
    }
};
int hello_world() {
    std::cout << "Hello World! \n";
    return 0;
}
int hello_world2() {
    std::cout << "Hello World 2! \n";
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    std::vector<endpoint_t<???>> array;
    array.push_back(hello_world);
    array.push_back(hello_world2);
}
```

Comment: Not much about memory leaks, but I have doubts that `m_func((void*) func)` is UB finally.

Comment: In terms of memory management: No leaks there for one simple reason: You don't allocate any dynamic memory at all. No malloc, no new, no anything. Hence, no memory leaks. On the other hand that cast to void and then back to func...well, technically it might work, since the content is actually sane, but why not store 'Func' in the template function in the first place?

Comment: Why do you save a void pointer, if your class is a template anway? And no functions must not be deleted to prevent memory leaks, (no new -> no delete required). And usually code can not be modified at runtime.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Well the goal of the structure is to be able to hold different `hello_world` functions inside an array. But I haven't figured it out yet. I will create a small example of the goal. Good to know about the memory leaks, I forgot the simple rule.

Comment: What you may be looking for is the combination of `std::function<void ()>` and `std::bind`, which allows you to store any sort of function pointer in a functor object, which can then be called at any given time.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Okay great to hear this is possible, could you perhaps provide a mini example? This would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the prototypes of all your 'hello world' functions is the same (int return value, no parameter), you don't need templates at all. Just store a function pointer.

```
typedef int (*Func_t)();
int hello_world() {
    std::cout << "Hello World! \n";
    return 0;
}
int hello_world2() {
    std::cout << "Hello World 2! \n";
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    std::vector<Func_t> array;
    array.push_back(&hello_world);
    array.push_back(&hello_world2);
}
```

Assuming that the prototypes do differ, it becomes a wee bit more difficult, but not very much so, thanks to `std::function`.

```
int hello_world() {
    std::cout << "Hello World! \n";
    return 0;
}
int hello_world2(int value) {
    std::cout << "Hello World 2! \n";
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    std::vector<std::function<int ()>> array;
    array.push_back(&hello_world);
    array.push_back(std::bind(&hello_world2, 2));
}
```

Please note, that `std::bind` and lambdas require you to pass any given parameter at the time of binding. You cannot add the parameter later.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! For the detailed explanation and the optional change in prototypes! Great answer, unfortunately can't upvote.